# How to initiate windows copy folder dialog with AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

How to initiate windows copy folder dialog instead of the ahk's FileCopyDir? My requirement is simple, I have a source and destination folder. source should be copied to dest folder by windows' copy folder dialog.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use AutoHotkey's `FileCopyDir` function, you can use the Run command in AutoHotkey to execute the native Windows copy command (`xcopy`).

```
sourceFolder := "C:\Path\to\source\folder"
destinationFolder := "C:\Path\to\destination\folder"

Run, xcopy "%sourceFolder%" "%destinationFolder%" /E /I /Y
```

The /E parameter ensures that all subdirectories, including empty ones, are copied. The /I parameter treats the destination as a folder if it doesn't exist. The /Y parameter suppresses the prompt to confirm overwriting existing files.

Please note that the availability of the copy folder dialog may vary depending on the Windows version.